How to add Specific Height to react grid layout Container so that elements can only move inside that and container height doesnt increase
Hello Every One this is my code in react for making a widget Playground Where i want to add fix heigh to react grid layoutplayground / the actual container where widgets will be dragged / move , i am adding fix height using css but thats not working its height only increase when either cell height increased or items or placed vcertically .
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState,useMemo } from "react";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import "/node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css"
import "/node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css"
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
import "./index.css"

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);
 
const WidgetsPlayground = () => {


  const [layout,setLayout] = useState(  [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1,  },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1,  },
    { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
    
  ])

  const handleLayoutChange = (newLayout) => {
   setLayout(newLayout)
  
  };

  const widgets = useMemo(() => {
    return layout.map((item) => (
      <div
        key={item.i}
        data-grid={{ x: item.x, y: item.y, w: item.w, h: item.h }}
        isDraggable={true}
        className="bg-gray-200 flex items-center justify-center text-[30px] "
      >
        <img src="/media/dashboard/widget-1.svg"  />    
      </div>
    ));
  }, [layout]);
  

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[calc(100vh-70px)] p-12 overflow-hidden  ">
      {/* <div  style={{height:"700px"}} className="w-full  grid-stack-container border-[1px] border-new_gray_300 bg-new_purple_700">
      </div> */}
        <ResponsiveGridLayout
          className=" layout border-[1px] border-new_gray_300 bg-new_purple_700"
        
          cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6,  }}
          breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, }}
          rowHeight={100}
          width={1200}
          isDraggable={true}
          isResizable={true}
          onLayoutChange={handleLayoutChange}
        >
        
        {
          widgets
        }
        </ResponsiveGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WidgetsPlayground;


i just want to have a bounded container with fix height and width where i can move widgets inside the bounded container and item doesnt overflow too in css its not working
